# Can't open video on android 12 that was captured by MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-12

```
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).also { takeVideoIntent ->
        takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_VIDEO)
        }
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            var videoUri = data?.data
            val intent = Intent(this, AddActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(VIDEO_URI, videoUri);
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
```

In the second Activity when I try to open the uri of the video in videoview
I'm Getting this exeption:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/.pending-1648411601-VID_20220320_200641.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I found a solution that solves the problem:
adding to menifest MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

But google play doesn't accept my app with this permission.

What are the alternatives if any?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, this would be one activity, not two, using fragments or composables for the individual screens.

However, if you absolutely need to get the `Uri` to another activity in your app:

- Attach it to the `Intent` you use to start that other activity via `setData()`
- Add `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(this, AddActivity::class.java)
    .setData(videoUri)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

`AddActivity` would call `getData()` on the `Intent` to retrieve the `Uri`.

Without this approach, `AddActivity` [has no rights to access the content](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: I tried this solution and still I'm getting:     java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/.pending-1648489848-VID_20220321_175048.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
 exeption on android 12.

Comment: @LevT.: It looks like you are getting a temporary `Uri` for some reason, probably due to bugs in whichever camera app you are using. You might consider switching to using `EXTRA_OUTPUT` and telling the camera app where you want the video to be recorded, ensuring that it is a location that your app can use.

Comment: It looks like this solution works, actually I use EXTRA_OUTPUT for photos. However now I have a strange bug on android 12 emulator (not real device) with this aproach the duration of the video is 3 hours and a half when the real duration is about 3 seconds. On android 11 in real device this aproach works like a charm.

Comment: I checked on a real android 12 device, it works just fine. look like a bug on android 12 emulator of android studio. CommonsWare thank you very much!